# How can I get information from database correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a trouble with mongoDB and Mongoose. I need to store data in mongoDB, because I use it for saving settings. Settings must load when app initializes. The trouble is that database does not always return data. Here are the screenshots to make everything clear:

1. 'Setup' array is returned.
2. 'Setup' array is not returned.
3. 'Setup' array returned 'undefined', so script can't run.

[image]

[image]

[image]

1-3 steps are done randomly!
My question is: how to connect to DB right? Is there any problems with the DB connection? (OS - Linux mint 19)

I tried several ways to connect to this DB:

**Setup.find({}).exec()**

**Setup.findById('...').exec()**

etc.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/config', { useNewUrlParser: true });
const setupSchema = new Schema({
    eula: Boolean,
    lang: String,
    styles: Number
});

mongoose.set('debug', true);


setupSchema.set('collection', 'setup');


const Setup = mongoose.model('Setup', setupSchema);
var eula, lang, styles;

Setup.findById('5ccfaf5a0c3c1612d4e2c905', function(err, setting){
    if (err) {
        console.log('Setup Init error');
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Setup Contents');
        if (setting !== null || setting !== undefined){
            console.log(setting[0]);
            // eula = setting[0].eula;
            // lang = setting[0].lang;
            // styles = setting[0].styles;
        } else {
            console.log('Setting is null');
        }

    }

});
```

I expect that the data will ALWAYS be returned.
Actual output is shown on screenshots (see above).

UPD: I've now reached this state (on the screenshot below), but still it is not good...

[image]

UPD2: I've found the solution! I tried to use MongoDB.Client, not mongoose.

Comment: Whole code: https://github.com/thesiv95/ids-parser/tree/dev

Comment: File index.js, lines 50-84

Comment: It asks you to add an error handler. Why don't you?

Comment: I decided not to add handler because of line 125 

`if (eula === undefined && lang === undefined && styles === undefined) {
    console.log('База не загрузилась, берем изменения по умолчанию');
    eula = true;
    lang = 'uk';
    styles =1;
}`

Comment: 'База не загрузилась, берем изменения по умолчанию' = 'DB is not loaded, we will use default values'=)

Comment: Actually it does not return CONNECTION ERROR, so error handler is useless

Answer (score 1):

I guess findById function will return an object and not an array.That's why you get this error.
**TRY THIS:**

```
Setup.findById('5ccfaf5a0c3c1612d4e2c905', function(err, setting){
    if (err) {
        console.log('Setup Init error');
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Setup Contents');
        if (setting){
            console.log(setting);
            // eula = setting.eula;
            // lang = setting.lang;
            // styles = setting.styles;
        } else {
            console.log('Setting is null');
        }

    }

});
```

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
Setup.findOne({id :'5ccfaf5a0c3c1612d4e2c905'}, function(err, setting){
        if (err) {
            console.log('Setup Init error');
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Setup Contents');
            if (setting){
                console.log(setting);
                // eula = setting.eula;
                // lang = setting.lang;
                // styles = setting.styles;
            } else {
                console.log('Setting is null');
            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: yeah, I tried to run this code; setting returns no error but 'null', but I can't understand why isn't there any data?

Comment: does id in your DB spell id instead of _id? if yes then try the updated code.

Comment: I tried both variants. I see that mongodb debugger outputs this:
`Mongoose: setup.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5ccfaf5a0c3c1612d4e2c905") }, { projection: {} })
Mongoose: snortrecords.find({ ids_name: 'Snort' }, { projection: {} })
Setup Contents
Setting is null`

Comment: `projection: {}` - could it be the reason?